# Не получается вызвать Activity из AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

После окончания операции вызывается метод `onPostExecute` у меня в этом методе сравниваются значения двух переменных и в зависимости от результата должно вызвать определенное Activity.
Eclipse ругается на некоторые строки в методе:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        if (nav2Reg.equals(noAuth)) {
            Intent intentA = new Intent(this, Auth.class); //Ругается
            startActivity(intentA);
        }else{
            Intent intentB = new Intent(this, Accaunt.class); //Ругается
            startActivity(intentB);
        }
    }
```

Как мне реализовать это условие правильно?

Comment: Служебное слово `this` в данном случае относится к классу `AsyncTask`, который не содержит контекста. Контекст в себе содержит только класс `Activity`, поэтому только в пределах активити вы можете указывать `this` там, где по сигнатуре требуется контекст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `onPostExecute()` относится к классу `AsyncTask`, соответственно в конструктор `Intent` вы пытаетесь передать экземпляр класса `AsyncTask`, однако конструктор выглядит так `Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`, поэтому создание `intent'a` для запуска ваших `activity` надо изменить на `new Intent(MyActivity.this, Auth.class)`

Дам совет как можно было решить данную проблему в течении минуты: надо всего лишь навести курсор на то, что не нравится eclips'y и через пару секунд появится подсказка, где будет описано недовольство eclips'a.